# Static reference to 'this' instance of a Class without ever instantiating an instance of the Class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static

I am programming in C# in Unity3D and was learning about object pooling when I came across a similar kind of code:

```
public class MyClass : Object
{
    public static MyClass current;

    void Awake()
    {
        current = this;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {

    }
}

public class Other
{
    void AnotherMethod()
    {
        MyClass.current.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

Now the class MyClass is non static, however the reference 'current' to its instance 'this' is(static).
I can invoke public non-static methods and access all other public non-static variables by using the static reference 'current' to the 'this' instance from within other classes.

But if I never created an instance of the class MyClass, what does the static reference point to?

Comment: You didnt found any better name than `Class`?

Comment: Have a look at the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern.

Comment: @kyle Sorry! My bad. I edited it to MyClass.

Answer (score 1):

The class `Class` has a static field holding a reference to a single instance of itself. If you try to access it from the class `Other` without assigning a valid value for `current`, you'll get a `NullReferenceException`.

The instance could be created anywhere (as it is a public static field), for example at some startup code. Using the singleton pattern, the class would have a private constructor and a `GetInstance` (or `GetCurrent`) method which would create an instance of the class when it is called and `current` is null.

You can't call `Awake()` without having an instance, so it may be initialized like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    // without this call, x.AnotherMethod will throw an exception.
    new Class().Awake();

    var x = new Other();
    x.AnotherMethod();
}
```

The given pattern should be avoided when possible as it has the meaning of a global variable. You can't be sure at any point of time which instance the `current` field points to. If the class `Class` has no internal state, it can be marked as static and only expose static methods.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I referred to the lesson again and it does actually initialize the object later in the code. The "current" is just a static reference. If I don't initialize it later, it throws me a null reference exception. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It'll point to nothing, and thus it will throw a null reference exception

Comment: I'm really sorry. That is exactly what is happening. I referred to the lesson and it is actually getting initialized later. The current is just a reference that's not intialized.